# How to find all occurrences of a pattern and their indices in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, shortcut

Is there a pythonian or shorthand way to get all pattern occurrences from a string and their indices? I can write a method that does it, I'm just wondering if there's a super short one-liner or something :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

python [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module to the rescue.

```
>>> import re
>>> [x.start() for x in re.finditer('foo', 'foo foo foo foo')]
[0, 4, 8, 12]
```

[`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) returns a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), what this means is that instead of using [list-comprehensions](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html) you could use in in a `for-loop` which would be more memory efficient.

You could extend this to get the span of your pattern in the given text. i.e. the start and end index.

```
>>> [x.span() for x in re.finditer('foo', 'foo foo foo foo')]
[(0, 3), (4, 7), (8, 11), (12, 15)]
```

Isn't Python Awesome :) couldn't stop myself from quoting [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/353/), downvotes or no downvotes...

[image]

Comment: How would you get the actual pattern?